# Como adicionar uma borda em um TextView por código?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou fazendo um formulário dinâmico e gostaria de adicionar uma bordar em volta de um conjunto com um TextView e um EditText como no código abaixo:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(vet[0]);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setSingleLine();
        et.setText("");
```

Gostaria de colocar este conteúdo em uma borda bem simples mesmo, como é possível de uma maneira bem simples

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil e resolveu o problema marque como correta @daniel12345smith, assim outro poderão se beneficiar.

Answer (score 3):

**VIA .XML**

Criei um arquivo .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="sua cor" />

</shape>
```

Com isso você pode aplicar dentro de seu TextView um "plano de fundo" que na verdade se trata de uma borda.

```
<TextView
      android:background="@drawable/text_view_border" />
```

**Via código :**

```
et.setBackgroundDrawable(new Border("cor","espessura));
```